# How to fix static noise in headphones on Dell XPS 13 9350 after new kernel patches

Tags: kernel, audio, alsa, realtek, jack

Dell XPS 13 9350 and 9360 have a long history of issues with static noise in headphones (see for example this [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336790/how-to-prevent-white-noise-in-headphones-on-dell-xps-13-9350-9360#)).

A [fix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581386/410474) has been recently proposed and pushed to most new kernels. However, in my case, static noise is still present, after the fix.

Previously, the noise could be avoided with a [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336834/410474) change of headphone mic boost setting in alsamixer.
Now, after the patch, that workaround is not available anymore. There is a small gain in volume (which is generally very loud anyway, so not really an advantage for me), but a constant static noise is back and very noticeable, even if quieter than previously (it stops on mute, and was absent with the alsamixer workaround using the same hardware, system and headphone/speakers).
I also believe that another recent kernel change (in the last few weeks), before the most recent proposed fix, had solved the noise problem without need for the workaround.

Is there some issue with the way it was patched or an unforeseen side effect? Can we find a solution?

I use a Dell XPS 13 9350, currently with Kernel 5.6.8. Please let me know if there are ways in which I can provide more helpful information.

Thank you!